# How to make a css grid switch from 3 columns to 2 columns + 1 column below with full width?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I have a row component that can take different grid layouts. One of the row has 3 columns. When switching to a tablet breakpoint, I need to switch to a two rows layout: 2 columns + 1 column that take the full width.

```js
const RowTemplate = {
  TwoLeft: { desktop: "2fr 1fr", tablet: "repeat(2, 1fr)", mobile: "1fr" },
  Three: { desktop: "repeat(3, 1fr)", tablet: "repeat(2, 1fr)", mobile: "1fr" },
};

const Row = styled.div<{
  format: { desktop: string; tablet: string; mobile: string };
}>`
  display: grid;
  @media (min-width: 400px) {
    grid-template-columns: ${({ format }) => format.mobile};
    > &:last-child {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    grid-template-columns: ${({ format }) => format.tablet};
  }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    grid-template-columns: ${({ format }) => format.desktop};
  }
`;

export default function Dashboard() {
return (
 <Row format={RowTemplate.Three}>
          <Column1/>
          <Column2/>
          <Column3/>
          <Tile
        </Row>
)
}
```

Currently, the last column goes to a second line, but only takes 50% of its width. How tp fix this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: You could try `grid-column: 1 / -1;` or `grid-column: span 2;` on that third element. But I don't see a simple way to integrate it into your setup.